# Unable to execute the wmic command through tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm executing the command `wmic process where Description="java.exe" get caption` through my tcl shell and getting below error:-

> Node - HAW-TEST-04
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid query

while the same commands runs perfectly from command terminal

```
`C:\>wmic process where Description="java.exe" get caption`
Caption
java.exe
java.exe
java.exe
java.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% exec wmic process where Description='java.exe' get caption
Caption

java.exe


%
```